# Do I need to link a .h and .m file if using the storyboard?

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I am trying to create a program that has one tableview and when you click on one of the rows, it links to another view controller (i.e. a new view controller or a new tableviewcontroller).
I have had great difficulty in creating a tableview controller that actually links to another view, despite following all the tutorials online. 
I finally got it by creating a new project which was a master view controller and then it worked because Xcode already set it up for me.
From here I want I have managed to link the rows to new screens, but now when i have one row link to another tableviewcontroller, i can't get the second tableviewcontroller to work.
I have done it in storyboard, and it all works if the second tableview controller isn't linked to a .h or .m file. As soon as a create a .h and .m file, i lose all the data I have entered in my table, and it no longer works.
If my second tableviewcontroller is only there to link to new view controllers, do i need the .h or .m files? Because as it stands, it is running fine on the emulator without them.

Comment: Can you provide any code examples, or at least better organize what you wrote?  It's a bit hard to follow what you're actually asking.

Comment: There is no code example because it isn't a coding issue. Its more of a storyboard issue. I just wanted a tableviewcontroller that only linked to new views. It was a static table with no other features on the screen. I wanted to know if, because there is no coding needed for anything on the screen, do i need the .h and .m files.

Comment: That's why I said 'or at least better organize what you wrote!' :)  But it seems the person below followed along better than I did as you accepted their answer, which is why we're all here, so it's all good! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my own experience in storyboarding UITableViewControllers only need .h & .m when you use dynamic prototype.

So:
1. UITableViewControllers with static cells do not need .h .m
2. UITableViewControllers with dynamic prototype need them for their delegates.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought that was the case.